# Database Operation Failed: Azure SQL and Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

```
Database operation failed on server 'worker.database.windows.net,11146' with SQL Error Number '40197'. Error message from database execution : The service has encountered an error processing your request. Please try again. Error code 4815.
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded..
```

I'm getting the following error. What does error code 4815 mean? Couldn't find any documentation regarding that error code.

Answer (score 2):

The error 4815 means that the SQL Server engine received an invalid column length from the bcp client for colid. You might want to check the parameters again and try this task again.

Here is some documentation on the error codes. Hope this helps.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645613(v=sql.105).aspx